# A strange phenomenon when using pcl::ApproximateGrid:

Tags: point-cloud-library, point-clouds

My environment is PCL 1.11.1 and vs2019.
I generated the synthetic point cloud using CloudCompare and I wanna downsample it.

So I use the following code

```cpp
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud_in(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
pcl::io::loadPLYFile("data_path", *cloud_in);

pcl::ApproximateVoxelGrid<pcl::PointXYZ> AVG_filter;
AVG_filter.setInputCloud(cloud_in);
AVG_filter.setLeafSize(2.0f, 2.0f, 2.0f);
AVG_filter.filter(*cloud_in);
```

But when I visualize cloud_in after filtering, the output is weird.

[raw input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTIAq.png)

[visualization output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lA95.png)

Can anybody explain this phenomenon to me? It will be so helpful

I don't know what's wrong with this. I really need some help

Comment: Can you post the synthetically generated point cloud?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to post the raw data. I have supplemented it in the question. It is the intersection of two planes.

Comment: I meant as a PLY file that I can download and load with PCL myself.

Comment: How to post the ply file? I can only find the 'image' upload button

Comment: You would have to use an external service like Dropbox, Google Drive, etc.

Comment: Ohhh！Thx！Here is the data. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pPiugwyK5cdlfoJ6Febjnd2Psbk538mX/view?usp=share_link Is it accessible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ApproximateVoxelGrid` works best when points that are close in Euclidean space (3D space), are also stored next to each other (in `cloud_in->points`). For point clouds that have been e.g. captured with a 3D camera, this is the case. On the other hand, it gives very bad results if the storage order is random, meaning that points which are stored next to each other are not close in Euclidean space. This is the case in your synthetic point cloud. I would recommend you to try `VoxelGrid` instead, or to find some way to order the points. For example like this: `std::sort(cloud_in->begin(), cloud_in->end(), [](auto& a, auto& b){ return (a.x < b.x); });`

Comment: You are right！ Really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

With IBitMyBytes's hint, I checked out the source code. I want to make a supplement to this problem from the essence, hoping to help others. The core of this problem is that `pcl::ApproximateVoxelGrid` uses a hash table to accelerate the extraction of centroids, but this also brings hash collisions. Whenever PCL encounters a hash collision, it will directly complete the centroid calculation of the current key-value linked list, which may cause points with similar Euclidean distances but large index differences to not be calculated yet, resulting in the effect of this problem.